# Is SandCastle a dead project?

Tags: .net, sandcastle, ndoc

Microsoft killed NDoc when they released a CTP/Beta version of Sandcastle, and I rarely see information about new version of a usable version of sandcastle (with an integrated UI for example). 
The latest realease is the May 2008 release.
Is Sandcastle a dead project or will it be included with Visual Studio 2010 ?

Comment: Doxygen is superior to SandCastle in so many ways (open source, multi-language, cross-platform, supports multiple commenting styles including JavaDoc and XML) and well-maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A new release is imminent](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=209712) - it has been delayed, but should be available pretty soon. It is expected to be a noticeable update, including support for .NET 4.

Comment: The last version was indeed released 2 days after your answer... but it's been almost a year, and there has been no update since then. Out of 173 reported issues, only 13 were closed, and that was 3 years ago... I'm starting to believe Sandcastle is a dead project, and there are no alternatives that produce similar results :S

Answer (score 3):

Well, according to their [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/sandcastle/), the latest version was used to build the documentation used to ship Visual Studio 2010 Beta 1, so the project does not look dead. Granted, that post was on July 2nd, 2009, so it is questionable how many changes are going into it...

Comment: I already watched their blog. Their last post was in July 2009 and there is no news since this time. It does not seem to be a wealthy project...

Answer (score 1):

Sandcastle itself may not have changed in a while, but it is the engine. The supporting tools, such as [SHFB](http://www.codeplex.com/SHFB) have had recent releases.

Comment: It's shame Microsoft does not provide any integration within Visual Studio but instead is waiting for third parties developers to build GUI on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try [contacting the developer](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/contact/StevenPei?OriginalUrl=http%3a%2f%2fwww.codeplex.com%2fsite%2fusers%2fview%2fStevenPei), Steven Pei?  He's been online on that site within a few months, so that's a good sign, at least.